# Selection on table view causes parent view to change

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app and here's my scenario:

I have a view which contains a table view inside of it. When the user selects an item on the table view, I would like the parent's view to change in a navigational manner. For those of you that have an iPad, this would be akin to the "Settings" app. But I guess in the "Settings" app, the right pane is composed of a grouped table view right?

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITableView` delegate receives any notification on selection and navigational events. Use this methods to simply synchronize the state in the dependent parts of your view.